# TFS not honoring /author argument with gated build

Tags: tfs, gated-checkin, tfs-code-review

We'd like to have a process like the following:

1. User submits code review with shelveset of changes they want to be in master branch.
2. If code passes review, select group of users can pull down the shelveset, and merge the changes into master using the original authors name for historical tracking.

I can use the `tf checkin /author:{OriginalAuthor}` command, but this doesn't work with our gated build. If I bypass the gated build, it will check in on the original authors behalf, but using the gated build it seems to pull the Author from the shelveset which is still marked as coming from my account/workspace and not the `/author`.

So I'm wondering, is there a way to have the gated build honor the `/author` argument for the final check-in that it performs?

Answer (score 0):

I just tested in TFS 2015.3, and enable a Gated Check-in in new build system.

If I use `tf checkin /author:A`, I'll get a shelveset with message below:

> Your check-in has been placed into shelveset
>   Gated_2016-10-27_01.53.28.8457;B and submitted for validation by build
>   definition \ScrumProject\Visual Studio.

[image]

Once user B request a review, user A re-run command `tf checkin /author:A`, you'll see the message below, and the change has been checked in by user A.

[image]